# EJS dynamic hyperlink issue

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to make a hyperlink that grabs the post id from my database and creates a link based on the postID but it doesn't seem to work

posts.ejs

```
 <% for (let post of userPosts) { %>
            <% if (currentTopic !== post.name) { %>
                <li><strong><%= post.name %></strong></li>
                <% currentTopic = post.name; %>
            <% } %>
            <li>
                <a href="/article/<%= post.post_id %>"><%= post.post_name %> - <%= post.username %></a>

            </li>
        <% } %>
```

main.js

```
  app.get('/article/:postId', function(req, res) {
        const postId = req.params.postId;
        const sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_id = ?';
    
        db.query(sqlQuery, [postId], (err, result) => {
            if (err || result.length === 0) {
                // Handle error or post not found
                res.send('Post not found.');
            } else {
                const post = result[0];
                res.render('article.ejs', { post });
            }
        });
    });
```

I can't seem to find the issue

Database

```
*create posts table
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `post_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` int NOT NULL,
  `post_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `article` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `post_id_UNIQUE` (`post_id`)
)
```

I've logged my errors down but i do not get anything when i click on the hyperlink

Comment: What *does* happen when you click on the hyperlink? Is the hyperlink coded correctly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It says cannot get /article/ 404 error not found

Comment: At first I had the hyperlink as <a href="/posts/<%= post.post_id %>"><%= post.post_name %> - <%= post.username %></a>